# Making my button turn my page black when you click on it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have been trying to make a toggle button that when pressed, would turn the page black for my own eyes sake, but have been unable to do so. Here is how it looks when i try: https://gyazo.com/5cd21085350b603f9289bb5f64b2361e I'am not good with JavaScript so its not that complicated. I have my button that looks like this:

```
        <label class="switch" onclick="pagecolor();">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
function pagecolor(){
    if(document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: A single equal sing (`=`) is used in assigning a value to a variable, for example `var x = 'white'`. For comparison, use double equal sign (`==`) for example `if (x == 'white'){ //code }else{//code}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition is incorrect, it always evalutes to true because you're asigning with single = sign, use ==

```
function pagecolor(){
    if(document.body.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried Lone Wolf but it did not work unfortunately :/

Comment: Here is the working demo with my code : https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp

Perhaps something else is wrong with your code that you haven't shared

Comment: I did just check and it is my css that is causing the problem. Making the check box not matching with my button correctly so when clicked it did nothing